# WPF binding - Updating Viewmodel property not updating abstract usercontrol view's property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, wpf-controls

I have a viewmodel and an abstract usercontrol view. However, updating the viewmodel doesn't update the view.

In short, updating IsSelecting in the viewmodel doesn't update IsSelecting in the view.

Here's the code:

Viewmodel:

```
public class ChartsStagesAndStatsViewModel: ObservableObject
{
    public ICommand StartCommand => new DelegateCommand<object>(StartButtonClicked);

    protected void StartButtonClicked(object obj)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Entered function: {nameof(StartButtonClicked)}"); // This properly gets logged

        ChartsStagesAndStatsViewModel.IsSelecting = true;
        // TODO
        ChartsStagesAndStatsViewModel.IsSelecting = false;
    }

    protected bool _isSelecting = false;
    public bool IsSelecting {
        get => _isSelecting;
        set {
            _isSelecting = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsSelecting));
        }
    }
}
```

Viewmodel base class:

```
public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Abstract view:

```
public abstract class LightningChartView : UserControl
{
    public bool IsSelecting
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsSelectingProperty); }
        set {
            Debug.WriteLine("IsSelecting"); // This never gets logged
            if (value == IsSelecting)
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(IsSelecting)} already has the value {value}. Each call to {nameof(IsSelecting)} = {true} has to come with a matching {nameof(IsSelecting)} = {false}.");

            SetValue(IsSelectingProperty, value);
            
            // TODO
        }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSelectingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsSelecting", typeof(bool), typeof(LightningChartView), new PropertyMetadata(false));
}
```

Concrete view:

```
public sealed partial class LightningChartStrokeVolumeXElastanceView : LightningChartView
{
    public LightningChartStrokeVolumeXElastanceView ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

XAML view:

```
<local:LightningChartView
x:Class="PerfusionMap.Common.Gui.Wpf.Views.ChartsView.LightningChartStrokeVolumeXElastanceView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PerfusionMap.Common.Gui.Wpf.Views.ChartsView"
         mc:Ignorable="d" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="SVxEV"
         >
    <Grid x:Name="grid">

    </Grid>
</local:LightningChartView >
```

Container XAML view:

```
<customViews:BaseView 
        x:Class="PerfusionMap.Common.Gui.Wpf.Views.ChartsStagesAndStatsView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PerfusionMap.Common.Gui.Wpf.Views"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         xmlns:customControls="clr-namespace:PerfusionMap.Common.Gui.Wpf.Controls"
         xmlns:customViews="clr-namespace:PerfusionMap.Common.Gui.Wpf.Views" 
         xmlns:chartsViews="clr-namespace:PerfusionMap.Common.Gui.Wpf.Views.ChartsView"
         xmlns:statsControls="clr-namespace:PerfusionMap.Common.Gui.Wpf.Views.StatsView"
         xmlns:enumsCommon="clr-namespace:PerfusionMap.Common.Core.Interfaces;assembly=PerfusionMap.Common.Core" 
         xmlns:buttons="clr-namespace:PerfusionMap.Common.Gui.Wpf.CustomControls.Buttons"    
         xmlns:arrowAxisUpdatePaths="clr-namespace:PerfusionMap.Common.Core.Helpers;assembly=PerfusionMap.Common.Core"
         AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ChartsStagesAndStatsView"
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <chartsViews:LightningChartStrokeVolumeXElastanceView VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    DataContext="{Binding}"
                    IsSelecting="{Binding IsSelecting, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    />

    <customControls:CustomButton
                    Command="{Binding StartCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="test"
                    />

</customViews:BaseView>
```

Container view code behind:

```
public partial class ChartsStagesAndStatsView
{
    public ICommand ChartsViewSizeChanged { get; set; }

    public ChartsStagesAndStatsView(ChartsStagesAndStatsViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

If any relevant piece of code is missing, let me know and I'll add it.

So, why is the IsSelecting property in the view not changing when IsSelecting in the viewmodel changes?

Comment: The Binding is executed after invoke of command and because your command is sync there is no change

Comment: @SirRufo I don't understand what you mean. You think doing something like Dispatcher.BeginInvoke would be the way?

Comment: When you click on the Button the bound Command is invoked. When that invokation returns the Binding will happen. Your Command is sync so the Binding will happen when all code of the Command has completed.

Comment: @SirRufo Unfortunately, I don't think that's what is happening. Debug.WriteLine($"Entered function: {nameof(StartButtonClicked)}"); is properly executed (the line shows up in the log), while Debug.WriteLine("IsSelecting"); is never logged, suggesting that IsSelecting doesn't get set at all in the view.

Comment: Be aware that the setter of the CLR wrapper of a dependency property is not called when the property is set by a Binding. The framework directly calls SetValue. The setter must therefore not contain any other code than the SetValue call.

Comment: @Clemens Thank you so much. That seems to be it. Edit: Works, thanks Clemens.